# SugarCRM Javascript/JQuery phone mask not fully working like I want it to work

Tags: javascript, php, sugarcrm

The mask works perfectly I got it working to the point that it will remove everything except the country code from the front of the number when I copy and paste it. So my problem now is that when I copy and paste like for example a number like this +1(999)999-9999 the output is coming out like 199-999-999 and I need it to come out like 999-999-9999. Don't know what exactly I'm missing if anyone can help me with this it would be great.

Tried everything I could think of.

```
_render: function() {
    this._super('_render');

    var SPMaskBehavior = function (val) {
        return '000-000-00009';
    },
    spOptions = {
        onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
            var value = e.target.value;
            if(value.length > 11) {

                if(value[0] == '1' || value[0] == 1) {
                    var res=value.slice(1, 13);
                    $('.republic_phone').val(res);
                }
                else {
                    var res =value.slice(0, 12);
                    $('.republic_phone').val(res);
                }
            }
            field.mask(SPMaskBehavior.apply({}, arguments), options);
            }
    };

    $('.republic_phone').mask(SPMaskBehavior, spOptions);   
},
```

I expect when I copy and paste any phone number like +1(999)999-9999 or even +1999999999 well really anything that looks like a phone I want to display it as 999-999-9999 Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also found out too if I type in 11111111111 like that my end result is 11-111-11111 and it should be 111-111-1111

Answer (score 0):

`999-999-9999` is 12 characters long, not 11.
Therefore I believe your entire code is off-by-one.

```
        if(value.length > 12) {

            if(value[0] == '1' || value[0] == 1) {
                var res=value.slice(1, 14);
                $('.republic_phone').val(res);
            }
            else {
                var res =value.slice(0, 13);
                $('.republic_phone').val(res);
            }
        }
```

Also it's weird you're using `$('.republic_phone').` in there to address the field.
 Shouldn't `field.` be the correct way to address the very field the function gets triggered for?

Comment: I got it working but I'm missing a number at the end